# what is wrong with this jquery drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have trying to create this jquery dropdown, but it doesn't work, Does anybody know If I am missing something in jquery or CSS

```
  <style type="text/css">
body{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
ul li{list-style-type:none;}
#cssdropdown{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
a{text-decoration:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;}
    .headLink{ display: inline-block; padding:10px;margin:10px;text-align:right;background-color:#999999;cursor:pointer;}
    .headLink ul{display:none;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".headLink").hover(function() {
            $('ul',this).css("display","block");
            $('ul',this).css("display","none");
        })
    })
</script>




<ul id="cssdropdown">
    <li class="headLink">Home
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Home5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="headLink">About
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="headLink">Contact
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Contact1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="headLink">Links
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Links1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Links5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am also not sure how `this` works with `ul` as a parameter. for function inside jquery
Thanks

Comment: You say it 'doesnt work', what does it do? Do you get any errors? Also, `this` inside the selector like that just means in the context of `this`, same as doing `$(this).find('ul')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters you are showing and hiding the ul on hover.
Change

```
$(function() {
        $(".headLink").hover(function() {
            $('ul',this).css("display","block");
            $('ul',this).css("display","none");
        })
    })
```

To

```
$(function() {
    $(".headLink").hover(function() {
        $('ul',this).css("display","block");
    }, function(){
        $('ul',this).css("display","none");
    })
})
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/swhwb/)

Comment: But my CSS is floating all over. The headlinks don't stay at top

Comment: @Mike That's not jQuery's problem, it's a CSS related issue. You have to use absolute positioning for this to work.

Comment: @Mike Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/swhwb/) will do, but of course you would have to work with CSS positioning. That makes for another question.

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to do this with pure CSS.

Remove the `<script>` tag, and replace your styles with these.
No change to the HTML structure.

```
<style>
    *{padding:0;margin:0}
    ul{list-style:none}
    a{text-decoration:none}
    a:hover{color:red}
    .headLink{float:left;height:30px;line-height:30px;padding:0 10px;cursor:pointer}
    .headLink ul{display:none;position:absolute}
    .headLink:hover ul{display:block}
</style>
```

Comment: Yeah, but unfortunately this is not cross-browser compatible :(

Comment: @Shef: Assuming you're talking about `.headLink:hover ul` - that will work in all browsers except IE6, for which simple (JavaScript) fixes are available.

Comment: @thirtydot That's what I was talking about. I agree, there are simple JS fixes, although the OP might want to add some effect when the submenu is shown or hidden. Thus, the simple JS fixes won't offer enough.

Comment: @Shef: That's fine, but you should say "this won't work in IE6" (which hardly matters) instead of "this is not cross-browser compatible" (sounds like a big problem!).

Comment: @thirtydot It will be hackish even in [IE7 and IE8](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover).

Comment: Frankly, I don't worry about IE6 anymore.

Comment: @Shef: In practise, (and from experience) those bugs are rarely an issue. The code suggested in this answer works fine in IE7/8, see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QXsKy/. I had to make a few changes to make it work in IE7. Note that *your demo* is currently broken in IE7 - it needs the same changes (amongst others) to work properly :)

Comment: @thirtydot You are right! I know my demo needs CSS fixes. I didn't even bother with the CSS, apart from adding an absolute positioning to give a hint to the OP for a start. Some people bother about IE6, some don't. I just wanted to point that out. You are right, I should have just said IE6 alone. However, your points are right. :)